# Mis variables de session se borran al pasar un par de minutos

Tags: php

Estimados estoy teniendo el siguiente dolor de cabeza. Realizo el login a mi aplicacion local de la siguiente forma, donde se crean las variables indicadas y se determina un cierto tiempo para que expire la sesion, lo cual se registra en una base de datos.

```
<?php 
include 'conexion.php';
$con = new Conexion();
session_set_save_handler(new \SessionHandler());
session_start();
$error = '';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['clave'])) {
        $error = "Por favor ingrese un usuario y contraseña validos";
    }else{
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $clave = $_POST['clave'];   
        $datos = $con->obtenerdatos("correo,clave,nombre,apellido,sid,idusuario","usuarios","correo = ?",array($usuario));
        if (count($datos) > 0){
            $fila = $datos[0];
            $clave = $fila['clave'];
            if(password_verify($_POST['clave'],$clave)){
                date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");
                $_SESSION['fecha'] = date("Y-m-d G:i:s");
                $_SESSION['correo'] = $fila['correo'];
                $_SESSION['nombre'] = $fila['nombre'];
                $_SESSION['apellido'] = $fila['apellido'];
                $_SESSION['idusuario'] = $fila['idusuario'];
                $_SESSION['sesion-start'] = time();
                $_SESSION['sesion-expire'] = $_SESSION['sesion-start'] + (15 * 60);     
                $sessionID = $fila['sid'];                          
                $actualizar = $con->actualizar("sesion_expira = ?,sid = ?","usuarios","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > sesion_expira",array(NULL,NULL));
                (new \SessionHandler())->destroy($sessionID);
                $_SESSION['sid'] = session_id();                
                $sid = $con->actualizar("sesion_inicia = ?,sesion_expira = ?,sid = ?","usuarios","correo = ?",array(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$_SESSION['sesion-start']), date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$_SESSION['sesion-expire']), $_SESSION['sid'], $_SESSION['correo']));
                header("location: ../profile"); 
                exit();
            }else{
                $error = 'La contraseña ingresada no es valida';
            }
        }else{
            $error = "El usuario ingresado no existe";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Luego en cada pagina que se debe estar logeado, verifico la sesion de la siguinte forma

```
<?php
session_start();
setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");
include "conexion.php";
$con = new Conexion();
if(!isset($_SESSION['correo'])){
    $con->desconectar();
    header('Location: '.$raiz.'login');
}else{
    $ahora = time();
    if($ahora > $_SESSION['sesion-expire']){
        $liberar = $con->actualizar("sid = ?","usuarios","correo = ?",array(NULL,$_SESSION['correo']));
        unset($_SESSION['fecha']);
        unset($_SESSION['nombre']);
        unset($_SESSION['apellido']);       
        unset($_SESSION['sesion-start']);
        unset($_SESSION['sesion-expire']);
        $con->desconectar();
        session_regenerate_id();
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: '.$raiz.'login');
    }else{
        date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");
        $_SESSION['sesion-expire'] = time() + (15 * 60);
        $actualizar = $con->actualizar("sesion_expira = ?","usuarios","correo = ?",array(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$_SESSION['sesion-expire']), $_SESSION['correo']));     
        $inactivos = $con->actualizar("sesion_expira = ?,sid= ?","usuarios","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > sesion_expira",array(NULL,NULL));
    }
} 

?>
```

Estoy realizando pagos de prueba, mediante un portal llamado Transbank, el cual luego de procesar la venta devuelve una serie de datos los cuales registro en una base de datos

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';include '../logica/conexion.php';
$con = new Conexion; 

use Transbank\Webpay\Webpay;
use Transbank\Webpay\Configuration;
use Transbank\Webpay\WebPayNormal;

$urlRepository = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TransbankDevelopers/transbank-webpay-credenciales/master/";
$dirFiles = "integracion/Webpay%20Plus%20-%20CLP/597020000540";
$contentPublicCert = file_get_contents($urlRepository . $dirFiles . ".crt");
$contentPrivateKey = file_get_contents($urlRepository . $dirFiles . ".key");
$configuration = new Configuration();
$configuration->setCommerceCode(597020000540);
$configuration->setEnvironment("INTEGRACION");
$configuration->setPrivateKey($contentPrivateKey);
$configuration->setPublicCert($contentPublicCert);
$webpay = new Webpay($configuration);
$transaction = $webpay->getNormalTransaction();

$tokenWs = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'token_ws');
$result = $transaction->getTransactionResult($tokenWs);
$output = $result->detailOutput;
$comercio = 'WebPay';
$total = $output->amount;
$query_cantidad = $con->obtenerdatos("cantidad","escala_creditos","total = ?",array($total));
$cantidad = $query_cantidad[0]['cantidad'];
$fechaautorizacion = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uT',$result->transactionDate);
$fechaautorizacion->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Santiago'));
$fecha = $fechaautorizacion->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$ordencompra = $output->buyOrder;
$codigoautorizacion = $output->authorizationCode;
$numerotarjeta = str_pad($result->cardDetail->cardNumber, 16, "X", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$idusuario = $_SESSION['idusuario'];
if($output->sharesNumber == 0){
    $numerocuotas = 0;
    $montocuotas = 0;
}else{
    $numerocuotas = $output->sharesNumber;
    $montocuotas = $output->sharesAmount;
}
if($output->paymentTypeCode == 'VD'){
    $tipoventa = 'Débito';  
}elseif($output->paymentTypeCode == 'VN'){
    $tipoventa = 'Normal';  
}elseif($output->paymentTypeCode == 'VC'){
    $tipoventa = 'En Cuotas';   
}elseif($output->paymentTypeCode == 'SI' or $output->paymentTypeCode == 'S2' or $output->paymentTypeCode == 'NC'){
    $tipoventa = 'Cuotas S/I';  
}elseif($output->paymentTypeCode == 'VP'){
    $tipoventa = 'Prepago'; 
}else{
    $tipoventa = '';    
}
if ($output->responseCode == 0) {
    
    echo '  <script>
                window.localStorage.clear();
                window.localStorage.setItem("result",JSON.stringify('.json_encode($result).'));
            </script>';
    

    
    $query = $con->insertar("?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?","creditos",array($ordencompra,$codigoautorizacion,$numerotarjeta,$numerocuotas,$montocuotas,$tipoventa,$total,$cantidad,$fecha,"Aprobada","123",$comercio,$idusuario));

    $query_creditos = $con->actualizar("creditos = creditos + ?","usuarios","idusuario = ?",array($cantidad,$idusuario));
}
?>
<?php if($output->responseCode == 0){?>
<form action="<?php echo $result->urlRedirection?>" method="post" id="return-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="token_ws" value="<?php echo $tokenWs;?>">
</form>


<script>
    document.getElementById('return-form').submit();
</script>
<?php }?>
```

La venta se realiza correctamente, pero luego en menos de 5 minutos mis variables de sesion se borran, por lo que al querer ejecutar nuevamente el script me da error con la variable $_SESSION['idusuario].
No se porque motivo se borran mis variables, ya que el script de verificacion caduca la sesion luego de 30 minutos. Que puede ser el motivo de que se borren las variables ?

Comment: verifica los timezones de la db y del script, y tal vez el locale deba ser `es_CL` para `"America/Santiago"`, otra es ver en php.ini el valor de `session.gc_maxlifetime` y `session.cookie_lifetime` que pueden estar calculando diferente los tiempos y te llaman al garbage collect antes de tiempo

Comment: ambos valores se encuentran en 1440, lo mas curioso es que las variables se borran solo despues de ejecutar el script que describi mas arriba